# Difference of opinion on duplicate question

Tags: discussion

A Python question (posted by another user) was marked as a duplicate with a link to the duplicate. The two questions had some similarities (about repeating an input prompt in a while loop until the user provides a valid input). However, there were several coding issues to fix besides the while loop (and a second `while` loop was required). Frankly, I didn't think it was a duplicate. Link to the question here:
*[Keep asking same question until valid number entered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53748376/keep-asking-same-question-until-valid-number-entered)*

I read SO Meta suggestions for this situation. Based on my findings, initially I posted my observations in the comments section. However, the question was still closed to answers.

Next I tried to flag the question as "in need of moderator intervention", but I was prompted with this:

> Don't flag mistaken duplicates; instead, edit the question: make the title specific and detailed then explain why the answers to the other question do not solve this problem.

So I tried to do that. I edited the question to add my explanation of the issues and corrections to the code. The edit was rejected as *"This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.*"

That is true...however I'm caught in an endless loop of SO Catch 22. I can't answer, and my comment had no impact. I wrote some code to help the OP...I am not sure how to share.

Comment: If your comment had no impact, it's likely the user doesn't want to improve to meet our standards. You have the choice of either asking a similar, but good question and answer it yourself, or wait for the OP of the other question to edit and make clear why it isn't a dupe.

Comment: Not being a Python expert, but I'm guessing that the posted code suggests that the poster is fairly new to the Python language, that there are several errors in the code, that the duplicate addresses the major thrust of the question, but that it misses some of the secondary problems, ones that you're trying to address. Is that correct?

Comment: Is your answer really going to be radically different than what is suggested in the duplicate post? Users have come to expect a tailor made answer, but a free bonus of the close-as-duplicate is often that they have to adapt the answer to their own situation. In general, I would consider that a good thing – even better than copy/paste ready code.

Comment: If so, then the duplicate closure should stand (or else the question should be closed for being too broad), since questions and answers should focus on one main specific thing. If we try to address all the errors in a newbies code, the site devolves from being a Q and A site to a mentoring site, and that is not what this site is for.

Comment: @usr2564301: We all try to be as helpful as we can when answering questions, but hate falling down the rabbit hole of feeding help vampires.

Comment: @Patrice. I got it. The OP needs to take ownership if his question wasn't addressed. I was frustrated b/c the question went from new to duplicate to closed for answers during the time I worked the solution. Sometimes an simple I/O error requires a not so simple modification. I doubt anyone that marked the post as a duplicate attempted to run his example (which was complete). They would have immediately noticed the answer didn't really address his problem. He had one `which` and needed a 2nd `which` for the 2nd input. Alas....

Answer (score 10):

The user gave a very clear problem statement:

> My query is, currently, if I enter charge as 101 it goes to the else section, and not asking again for a valid number. I would like it to loop round and keep asking until the user gives 0-100 number. How can this be done?

They did not say that they wanted help fixing every problem in their code. Sure, their code isn't indented properly. Sure, the break won't execute in the right place. Sure, the first line of input can throw a value error since it didn't make it into the try block. Sure, there are some other errors. But the user isn't asking about any of those things, the user is asking how to loop round and keep receiving input until the user gives a number between 0 and 100.

The duplicate specifically answers "How to keep repeating a program until a specific input is obtained?" which is what the user wanted to ask about.

If the user had asked "I want my code to do */entire problem statement/*. Will you debug and finish my code for me?" then you are right, it wouldn't be a duplicate, since there are more issues to deal with than just a loop. However, if the user had been asking for their entire code to be debugged, and not a specific issue that they had localized, then the question would be closed as "Too Broad" with the request to boil it down to a more minimal example and specific item to fix.

You are right that in general, if a question is incorrectly closed as a duplicate, commenting is the way to go. The notice about editing is generally for the question author, as a change of that sort will often go against the original intent (As your edit went against the user's intent; to find out how to keep looping until the user gave satisfactory input, on top of your attempt to give the answer to a question that wasn't asked as part of the question). However, in this case, the duplicate closure appears spot on.

Comment: I read all the comments and this answer. I will try to address. Not sure if I should comment here or with the other comments. I understand the OP asked "how to loop until the user gives the correct answer".

Comment: Some of my comments were lost in an edit. The correct answer requires a second `while` loop inside the 1st `while` loop. This is not explained by referencing the duplicate Q&A (might be inferred, but not obvious to a new user). Once the 2nd `while` is added other code changes are required to compensate. In addition, the 1st `while` is constructed incorrectly....which really should be addressed. This discussion served it's purpose...the OP reengaged on his question. :)